# Approach to display new items differently PFQueryTable

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, refresh, parse-platform

So I looked into the Anypic (https://github.com/ParsePlatform/Anypic/blob/master/Anypic-iOS) source and tried to replicate the idea.

I have a custom cell, this cell has the setIsNew:isNew just as Anypic teaches you. My PFQueryTableViewController has all the code related to the lastRefresh property.

BUT the lastRefresh is updated in the objectsDidLoad method, which is called BEFORE the cells are reloaded.

ViewController:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.lastRefresh = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"lastRefresh"];
}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    PFObject *obj = self.objects[indexPath.section];

...

    if ([self.lastRefresh compare:obj.createdAt] == NSOrderedAscending) {
        [cell setIsNew:YES];
    } else {
        [cell setIsNew:NO];
    }
    return cell;
}

-(void)objectsDidLoad:(NSError *)error
{
    [super objectsDidLoad:error];
    self.lastRefresh = [NSDate date];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:self.lastRefresh forKey:@"lastRefresh"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
}
```

Custom Cell:

```
- (void)setIsNew:(BOOL)isNew
{
    if (isNew) {
        [self.mainView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:1 green:0.9216 blue:0.5608 alpha:0.5]];
    } else {
        [self.mainView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    }
}
```

It results in nothing. The lastRefresh will always be later than the object.createdAt, so all cells will look exactly the same.

What am I doing wrong? Or is there another clever solution?

Thank you and sorry if it's a noob question.

Comment: `object.createdAt` is the date that you created the object in the database. why would `lastRefresh` be always earlier than `object.createdAt`?

Comment: by earlier I mean, more recent.

Comment: FYI when talking about dates "earlier" is commonly accepted to refer to a date further in the past, "later" is for dates that happen after another date.